# disable onEachFeature at zoom level Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

In there a way to disable onEachFeature at zoom level? I have a GeoJSON object with highlightFeature and resetHighlight functions. I want to disable resetHighlight at zoom level 8

```
    var rejon_3;
    function resetHighlight3(e) {
        rejon_3.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }

    function onEachFeature33(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature
        });
    }

    function x3(e) {map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds())}

    function onEachFeature3(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight3,
            click: x3
        });
    }


    rejon_3 = L.geoJson(exp_3, {
        style: style3,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature3
    }).addTo(map);

    feature_group.addLayer(rejon_3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In there a way to disable `onEachFeature` at zoom level?

No.

`onEachFeature` iterates through the features, regardless of zoom level. Even if the `L.FeatureGroup` they belong is never displayed. You're mixing concepts here.

> I want to disable resetHighlight at zoom level 8

Then make your `resetHighlight` event handler do nothing under certain conditions:

```
function resetHighlight(ev) {
  if (map.getZoom() > 8) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```